# HTTP request to the http address of an API with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

use Auth,Str,Storage,Image,DB;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;


class SmsController extends Controller
{
    //

    public function index()
    {
        //
        
        $data =[

            'title'=>$description='Envoie SMS',
            'description'=>$description,
            //'membre'=>$membre,
            //'membres'=>$membres,
            //'departement'=>$departement,
            
            
        ];
           return view('sms.index',$data);
    }

    public function envoyer(Request $request)
    {
        //
         

         $senderid=$request->senderid;

         $numero=$request->numero;

         $message=$request->message;

         $dateheure=date('Y-m-d h:i:s', time());

         //dd($dateheure);

         $client = new Client();

        $res = $client->request('POST', 'http://africasmshub.mondialsms.net/api/api_http.php', [
            'form_params' => [
                 'username' => 'test',
                 'password' => '0758224162',
                 'sender' => 'test',
                 'text' => 'Hello World!',
                 'type' => 'text',
                 'numero' => $numero,
                 'message' => $message,
                 'datetime' => $dateheure, 
            ]
        ]);

        //dd($res);
        
        $success = 'message envoyé avec succès';

     return redirect()->route('sms')->withSuccess($success);
    }
}
```

Hello everyone ! I have a problem with Laravel, I cannot make an Http request to the Http address of an API which should allow me to send SMS. I am sending you as attachments the source code of my Controller "Smscontroller.php". I need your help. Thank you !

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: Can you also write what error you are getting to the question?